# Reactive variables not updating with setContext/getContext

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a parent `Form` component:

```html
<script lang='ts'>
  export let data;
  $: validationResult = myZodSchema.safeParse(mydata);
  $: isValid = validationResult.success;

  setContext('my-form', {
    isValid
  })
</script>
```

Then my `SubmitButton` component:

```html
<script lang='ts'>
  const { isValid } = getContext('my-form');
</script>
```

isValid is always undefined in the `SubmitButton` even when it's true in `Form` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contexts are not reactive, closing over a reactive variable won't change that.

This is why it is recommended to use [stores](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store) in contexts if reactivity is required.

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
const isValid = writable(); // can also set initial value here
setContext('my-form', { isValid })

// ...
$: $isValid = validationResult.success;
```

```html
<script>
  // ...
  const { isValid } = getContext('my-form');
</script>
Form is valid: {$isValid}
```

Comment: This was the only thing I didn't tried before. Now it works as desired. Thank you!